# when building a flask-docker image/container is there a way to selectively load folders?

Tags: python, docker

is there a way to exclude files based on the env?

When I run the code for testing locally, I use a set of dependencies.

here is how I created the image:

```
docker build --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=local -t qube-dev-env:latest .
```

When I deploy the code on aws, I need a few extra dependencies.
here is how I created the image:

```
docker build --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=aws -t qube-dev-env:latest .
```

The reason why I want to run different dependencies in test vs production is for cost.

this is my Dockerfile::

```
# Dockerfile

FROM python:3.11.3

USER root

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

# Environment specific requirements
ARG ENVIRONMENT
ENV CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT=$ENVIRONMENT
COPY requirements-${ENVIRONMENT}.txt /app/
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements-${ENVIRONMENT}.txt

EXPOSE 80

ENV NAME World

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

I have the requirements segregated so that is not the issue.

Below is where I need to tell the app to differentiate on what folders to load and which ones to ignore::

```
def create_conversation_message_controller():
    print(f'create_conversation_message_controller()')
    
    environment = os.environ.get("CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT", "default_value")
    

    files_chuncks_embeddings = None
    message_embeddings = None
    
    labeled_files = text_extractor_util.extract_and_label_text_from_pdfs(files_blob)
    
    files_chuncks = token_chuncker_util.chunk_text_using_tokens(labeled_files,word_length=150, overlap=20)
    
    if environment=='local':
        from controllers.conversation_message.create_conversation_message.local_helper import get_local_embeddings
        files_chuncks_embeddings, message_embeddings = get_local_embeddings(message,files_chuncks)
        
    if environment=='aws':
        from controllers.conversation_message.create_conversation_message.aws_helper import get_aws_embeddings
        files_chuncks_embeddings, message_embeddings = get_aws_embeddings(message,files_chuncks)
```

is there a way to do this?

the issue is that everything is being loaded haha, which causes an issue about missing a dependecy

Comment: is it running the currect requirements file based on the environment?

Comment: Does this work?  Seems reasonable.

Comment: @Jeril yes





I think python reads all the files to compile, so thats where i get the error from

Comment: @TimRoberts it does not work.

Comment: Can you share the entire traceback?

Comment: ohhh jk.  i looked back at thetraceback and it was a error from a earlier file

Comment: thank you @Jeril for telling me where to look!!!